# os.path.expanduser(~) returns /var/www not /home/ubuntu

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I have a Flask app running on apache2, mod_wsgi inside a vitualenv. I am using subprocess from within the flask app to run a Python script. The Python script is located in `/home/ubuntu/scripts`. The script runs as expected however `os.path.expanduser('~')` does not return `/home/ubuntu` but `/var/www` instead.

So far my workaround was to remove `expanduser` and hardcode the path, but I'm interested why this is happening and if there is an easy fix.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Are you running `os.path.expanduser(~)` (without quotes) or `os.path.expanduser('~')` (with quotes)? If you are calling other commands using `os` or `os.path` posting sample code may help

Comment: Yes actual code: directory = os.path.expanduser('~/temp/') results in directory = /var/www/temp. I'm fairly certain the response from unutbu is the answer just not sure how to fix it yet but now I know where to start looking.

Answer (score 3):

The script may be running as user [`www-data`](https://askubuntu.com/q/873839/8005), whose home directory is defined in `/etc/passwd` by default as `/var/www`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to linux so I will need to read up on users and permissions but I think you are right. Can I change the home directory of www-data? Are there security concerns if I do change it to /home/ubuntu?

Comment: You shouldn't change it. If you want your code to run as a particular user, ensure you are using daemon mode of mod_wsgi and set the ``user`` and ``group`` options to ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` directive for the daemon process group. See options in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html